# Use a local GitLab Runner Docker container to run multiple jobs

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've been running GitLab jobs locally with GitLab Runner Docker image. The following shows how I execute a "test" job locally:

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD:$PWD -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /opt/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner --workdir $PWD gitlab/gitlab-runner exec docker test
```

However, every time I run this command, it starts up a new GitLab Runner Docker container, installs all dependencies in *before_script* and runs the "test" job. Installing dependencies takes up 95% of the time and I am wondering if it's possible to cache them across job runs but without having to push a new image to GitLab Container Registry.

Is this possible to do the following?

1. Start GitLab Runner Docker container and have it run continuously listening for instructions of which job to execute
2. Trigger job execution from the local OS, e.g. through an HTTP call or socket call to the container started in step #1. I am assuming that all dependencies installed by the previous job executions will still be available on the docker container giving me the caching functionality I am looking for.

What I am asking seems to be awfully close to GitLab Runner [shell executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-the-shell-executor) but I don't see where it takes the URL of the local container (started in step #1 above). Maybe I am just tripping up on the specific commands that need to be run, so if you can share such command, it'd be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify your use case a bit? I don't get why would you even need to trigger anything gitlab-runner related from local machine, what are you trying to do? Are you retesting existing code when environment changes? Why won't you just rerun job? The whole point of having a docker executor is to have clean environment every time you execute your pipline, and anything you need to cache should be put in `cache` part of your pipeline. Maybe add a `.gitlab-ci.yml` snippet so we can see a whole picture

Comment: I'd like to be able to test my jobs without having to push each change to GitLab because it creates too many unnecessary Git commits. I do rerun the job but I don't want it to spend 95% of the time installing dependencies on my Docker container. I tried putting my python venv in the ```cache``` section of ```.gitlab-ci.yml``` but python dependencies still get installed when I run the job using the command I mentioned in my original post.

Comment: Have you used this example? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-python-dependencies ? Simply archiving .venv won't be enough to make it work. If you still want to have some shared folder - you can configure one in your executor and pass it to all containers. It's still an antipattern, so i advise you  to configure a proper caching in gitlab itself.

Comment: Yes, I used a sample Python template from https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Python.gitlab-ci.yml but every time I execute the command shown in my original post, docker container re-installs all python dependencies. As I mentioned, I'd like to test my jobs locally without having to push every single commit to GitLab for testing. So, I'd like to refer back to my original post and ask if the 2-step process I described is possible to implement locally and if so, what commands implement each step?